# Django. How to get all fields in JOIN query and GROUP BY it all

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I need JOIN two table, and groping by `id` and get two aggregation func by some fields:

models.py

```py
    class Products(models.Model):
        brand = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
        cluster = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
        target_market = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Vardata(models.Model):
        month = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
        sales_units = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        fk_products = models.ForeignKey(MntProducts, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fk_products', blank=True, null=True)
```

Data:

```
Products.objects.all()
('vendor1', 'name1', 'it', 'C') #id-12
('vendor2', 'name2', 'it', 'B') #id-13
('vendor3', 'name3', 'bc', 'B') #id-14
```

....

```
Vardata.objects.all()
('2020-03-01', '20', '180', '12')
('2020-04-01', '15', '182', '12')
('2020-05-01', '10', '178', '12')
('2020-03-01', '30', '120', '13')
('2020-04-01', '35', '122', '13')
('2020-05-01', '10', '118', '13')
('2020-03-01', '20', '150', '14')
('2020-04-01', '15', '155', '14')
('2020-05-01', '10', '156', '14')
```

i need exit:

```
exit[0]
{'id': 12, 
'brand': 'vendor1', 
'name': 'name1', 
'cluster': 'it', 
'target_market': 'C',
'sum__sales_units': 540,
'avg__price': 180
}
```

I try to get from database `INNER JOIN` SQL Query with all fields from both table to `QuerySet`; and after to use `annotate(Sum('sales_units', Avg('price'))` to this `QuerySet`:

But my query don't take fields from parent table (Products) in query

views.py

```py
qry_total_execute = Vradata.objects.select_related("fk_products").filter(fk_products__in=list_products)
```

```
>>> qry_total_execute.query('SELECT `vardata`.`id`, `vardata`.`month`, `vardata`.`sales_units`, vardata`.`price_rur`, `vardata`.`fk_products`, `products`.`id`, `products`.`brand`, `products`.`name`,  `products`.`cluster`, `products`.`target_market` FROM `vardata` INNER JOIN `products` ON (`vardata`.`fk_products` = `products`.`id`) WHERE `vardata`.`fk_products` IN (12, 13, 14)
```

it write
`QuerySet` with right numbers of records, but without fields from `products` only from `vardata` (Using this SQL Query in MySQL by hands give right result with all needed fields.)

Asked Questions:

1. How to get all fields from booth database?
2. How to using aggregate correctly if i get right result for `qry_total_execute`?

```
    qry_total_execute.values('id', 'brand', 'name', 'cluster', 'target_market').'annotate(Sum('sales_units', Avg('price'))
```

Does it right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use model `Vardata`, let use `Products` and put `annotate` directly

```py
qry_total_execute = Products.objects.filter(id__in=list_products).\
        annotate(Sum(vardata__sales_units), Avg(vardata__price).\
        values()
```